# rapidly writing to a temp file and renaming it... is that a good idea?

Tags: linux, file-io, daemon

I have a daemon / service on a linux box (Debian 6) that reads from a hardware device, does some calculations and then updates a file with some relevant values. This happens about 5 times per second.

Any process that is reading the file always sees nicely structured and recent values in the file.

Here is the relevant daemon code:

```
while(1)
{
    int rename_ret;
    char tmpname[] = "/var/something/readout.tmp";
    char txtname[] = "/var/something/readout.txt";
    FILE *f = fopen(tmpname, "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    # ... reading from hardware, some calculation ...

    # then print to the tmp file:
    fprintf(f, "%12.4f\n", CntVal1);
    fprintf(f, "%12.4f\n", CntVal2);

    fclose(f);

    rename_ret = rename(tmpname, txtname);

    if(rename_ret != 0)
    {
            printf("Error: unable to rename the file");
            exit(1);
    }
    nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 200000000}}, NULL);  // 0.2 sec
```

}

This works fine, but it *feels* kind of... wronggg?

Note that this is not the device driver, but instead it reads from the driver and processes the values for other processes to read.

So my question is:

1. is this a bad idea?
2. what's the proper way to go about it? I like the idea to be able to "just read a file" and get fairly recent values...

Comment: opening/closing/renaming a file 300 times a minute makes me cringe a bit.  At a minimum, why not employ one file, keep it open, use file locks to synchronize access between programs, and just have the daemon seek back to wherever it needs to begin before rewriting?

Comment: @Duck because rename is supposed to be "atomic", and I don't know if I can make a write "atomic", so that some process reading the file won't ever catch it in a half-written state.

Comment: That's the point of the locks.  Your daemon doesn't give up the lock until its written whatever it needs to write and the other programs don't access the file until they can get the lock.  Flush if using stdio.